# NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/tracing/Trace

Tags: android, gradle, android-lifecycle, android-jetpack, android-testing

When I start a basic androidTest my app crashes:

```
@Test
fun myTest() {
    val scenario = ActivityScenario.launch(MainActivity::class.java)
    // ...
}
```

This is the stacktrace:

> 2022-04-27 08:43:38.438 28069-28069/myapp.test E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL
> EXCEPTION: main Process: myapp.debug.test, PID: 28069
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of:
> Landroidx/tracing/Trace;
> at androidx.startup.AppInitializer.discoverAndInitialize(AppInitializer.java:210)
> at androidx.startup.InitializationProvider.onCreate(InitializationProvider.java:45)
> at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1919)
> at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1894)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6273)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5839)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5747)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1669)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6528)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
> "androidx.tracing.Trace" on path: DexPathList[[zip file
> "/system/framework/android.test.mock.jar", zip file
> "/system/framework/android.test.runner.jar", zip file
> "/data/app/myapp.debug.test-4n8SpMC8qbT8ak5Kl9hJcQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/myapp.debug.test-4n8SpMC8qbT8ak5Kl9hJcQ==/lib/arm64,
> /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
> at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:125)
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
> at androidx.startup.AppInitializer.discoverAndInitialize(AppInitializer.java:210) 
> at androidx.startup.InitializationProvider.onCreate(InitializationProvider.java:45) 
> at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1919) 
> at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1894) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6273) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5839) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5747) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1669) 
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6528) 
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)

The following dependencies cause the problem:

```
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-process:2.4.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.1'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the dependencies which are listed in the example on this page:

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle#declaring_dependencies